# Set up C++ with Code::Blocks in Linux Mint

Tags: c++, linux, installation, codeblocks, linux-mint

Im new to C++ developing and can't get Code::Blocks to compile correctly. It exits with

> Process terminated with status -1

The program is a very basic 'Hello World' program.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

To set up my environment, I followed this guide step by step:
http://www.dummies.com/programming/cpp/how-to-install-c-codeblocks-in-ubuntu-linux/

Also researching the error:

> Process terminated with status -1

with google, does not give me the expected answer.

Any idea what could be wrong or need more information from me?

best wishes and thanks.

**Solution:**

In my case, xterm was not installed. after getting xterm with

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: This is most probably not a Code::Blocks problem, but some error in your code, though the snippet you give seems to be valid. Try debugging the code, running it in a debugger session in Code::Blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The debugger could give me more detailed information. **Can't launch console (xterm -T 'Program Console' -e sleep 80005749)** I installed xterm now and everything works fine.

Comment: Have you installed Code::Blocks with your OS package manager, or downloaded it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am running  C::B on Linux Mint and I had the same problem. The "problem" is that C::B uses xterm as it's default terminal. However, Mint 19 uses gnome by default, not xterm. You don't have to install xterm for C::B to work. First go to *Settings >> Environment*.
In C::B v16.01, at the bottom of the menu that opened there is a line and it's associated drop-down menu: *Terminal to launch console programs:*. In the drop-down menu select gnome (or other any other compiler that you use on your system) and it should work, rebuild and run!